# Joptionpane does not process switch-case

Tags: java, swing, switch-statement, joptionpane

Am having issues with my switch-case options and joptionpane. After selecting one of the four options the program ends. It doesn't display the selection. It should display the choice/selection.

```
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // JOptionPane call

  public class OnlineStore 
  {
     // public static void main(String[] args) // main program
      public void display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
      {
          String main_selection;
          int mSelect;

          main_selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!\n\n1. Add T-                Shirt Order\n2. Edit T-Shirt Order\n3. View Current Order\n4. Checkout\n\nPlease   enter your choice: ");
    mSelect = Integer.parseInt(main_selection);

      }

      public OnlineStore() // Switch-case program
      {
          display_menu(); // Call display menu.
          switch (mSelect)
          {
              case 1:
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 1");
                  break;
              case 2:
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 2");
                  break;
              case 3:
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 3");
                  break;
              case 4:  // Deliberately not including a default selection.
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 4");
                  break;  
           } 

      } 

      public static void main(String[] args) // main program
      {
          new OnlineStore(); // Call out the program.
      }
  }
```

When I use Scanner the results are ok.

Comment: I must say it works for me, after changing the code. The code you did provide does not compile. `mSelect` is only locally defined in `display_menu`

Comment: @kevin esche. Got it. It works! I also moved the "String main_selection" up one level into the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that there is no contextual relationship between what is happening in `display_menu` and what your processing in `OnlineStore`.

Instead, why not have `display_menu` return the selected value/option and include that in the `switch` statement, for example

```
public class OnlineStore {

    // public static void main(String[] args) // main program

    public int display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
    {
        String main_selection;

        main_selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!\n\n1. Add T-                Shirt Order\n2. Edit T-Shirt Order\n3. View Current Order\n4. Checkout\n\nPlease   enter your choice: ");
        return Integer.parseInt(main_selection);

    }

    public OnlineStore() // Switch-case program
    {
        switch (display_menu()) {
            case 1:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 1");
                break;
            case 2:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 2");
                break;
            case 3:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 3");
                break;
            case 4:  // Deliberately not including a default selection.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 4");
                break;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) // main program
    {
        new OnlineStore(); // Call out the program.
    }
}
```

## Looping Menu

```
public class OnlineStore {

    // public static void main(String[] args) // main program

    public int display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
    {
        String main_selection;

        main_selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!\n\n1. Add T-                Shirt Order\n2. Edit T-Shirt Order\n3. View Current Order\n4. Checkout\n\nPlease   enter your choice: ");
        return Integer.parseInt(main_selection);

    }

    public OnlineStore() // Switch-case program
    {
        boolean exit = false;
        do {
            switch (display_menu()) {
                case 1:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 2");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 3");
                    break;
                case 4:  // Deliberately not including a default selection.
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 4");
                    break;
            }
        } while (!exit);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) // main program
    {
        new OnlineStore(); // Call out the program.
    }
}
```

Comment: the switch-case function stops after one choice. I can't seem to get it to go back to OnlineStore( ). I tried do-while statement but the main menu pops up twice.

Comment: Where did you put the loop?  Presumably it should be wrapping the switch statement

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, the menu appears twice.

Comment: Not sure what code you're using, but something like the example above (note, it the example will never exit, but I assume one of your cases will eventually set the `exit` flag to true)

Comment: the switch-case function stops after one choice. I can't seem to get it to go back to OnlineStore( ). I tried do-while statement. It didn’t work.  May I create another question to share with you more of the code>

Answer (score 3):

Declare mSelect variable inside class not inside method.

```
public class OnlineStore {
int mSelect;
// public static void main(String[] args) // main program

public void display_menu() // Not the main program but the main menu.
{
    String main_selection;

    main_selection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome!\n\n1. Add T-                Shirt Order\n2. Edit T-Shirt Order\n3. View Current Order\n4. Checkout\n\nPlease   enter your choice: ");
    mSelect = Integer.parseInt(main_selection);

}

public OnlineStore() // Switch-case program
{
    display_menu(); // Call display menu.
    switch (mSelect) {
        case 1:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 1");
            break;
        case 2:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 2");
            break;
        case 3:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 3");
            break;
        case 4:  // Deliberately not including a default selection.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option 4");
            break;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) // main program
{
    new OnlineStore(); // Call out the program.
}}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer I checked  the code. int value return  from display_menu

Comment: @MadProgrammer, tried that. Didn't work. Gave me errors.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, sorry, you are right. Just ran it again. It works.

Comment: @rlee  if you declare mSelect variable inside class and outside method the code will be work

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, without the Scanner, no integer is set to `mselect` - so your switch choose the case `default` if you would define one like:

```
switch(mSelect){
.
.
.
default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
}
```

Another solution is that you set a default value to `mSelect` like

```
int mSelect = 1;
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the insight!